# collect data from dynamodb using nodered

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, node-red

I'm new to Node-RED and AWS. I want to collect data from AWS dynamodb and read it in Node-RED.

I have tried to use this nodejs code in function but it didn't work.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
"TableName" : 'admins',
"Key" : [
      { "username" : { "S" : "foo" } },
    ],
}

 db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('error: '+ err);
    console.log(data);
    return next();
    res.send(data);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Just saying it doesn't work makes it very hard for people to help. Please read the doc about asking good questions to learn how to improve this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Node-RED [documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#loading-additional-modules) about how to use npm libraries in function nodes.

You can not use `require()` in function nodes, but there is a work around using the function global context.

But also there are multiple AWS DynamoDB nodes listed on [flows.nodered.org](https://flows.nodered.org/?term=dynamodb&type=node&num_pages=1) that will let you interact with the database without needing to write function nodes.